# calling getMaxAmplitude returns 0

Tags: java, android

I am creating a project in witch I have to find the loudness of recorded sound.

No matter how many times I call `getMaxAmplitude()` it always show 0 and by writing `amplitudeDb` it always shows -infinity.

kindly help me thanks.

Here is my code.

```
record1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        record[0] = new MediaRecorder();
        record[0].setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        record[0].getMaxAmplitude();
        record[0].setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        record[0].setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        record[0].setOutputFile(FilePath);

        try {
            record[0].prepare();
            record[0].getMaxAmplitude();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            record[0].start();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

});

stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            record[0].stop();
        }

        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            int amp = record[0].getMaxAmplitude();
            //String ampl = amp.toString();
            int x = 1;
            System.out.println("amp: " + amp);
            System.out.println("hello");
            //double amplitudeDb = 20 * Math.log10((double) Math.abs(amp));
            ampli.setText("" + amp);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            record[0].release();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i understands the logic of getMaxAmplitude() ijust have to write record[0].getMaxAmplitude() just before record[0].stop()

everything willbe okay then :)